# How to orderBy Conversion Cost or CPA when writing to Google Sheets

Tags: google-apps-script

I'm using Google app scripts to write data to Google Sheets with custom calculations which is why I'm using scripts instead of a straight export of the data. When the data is written into Google Sheets, I want it sorted by Cost/Conv or CPA.

The current script sorts by Conversions:

```
var kw=AdWordsApp.keywords().withCondition("Conversions >1").withCondition("Status =ENABLED").forDateRange("20180101", "20180801").orderBy("Conversions DESC").withLimit(100).get();
```

How do I sort by conversion cost or cpa?

I looked through Googles documentation and even called their support team. Couldn't find the answer. I feel like this should be simple but I can't figure it out.

Comment: Why not sorting data in the spreadsheet after import ?

Comment: I've been doing that but figured, why not save myself a step. Just trying to make my life easier and figured this would be an easy thing to do within the script since sorting is a feature.

Comment: I guess you are building an array that you write to the sheet, then sort that array just before writing it to the sheet.